# Motivo de fechamento de uma pergunta errado, o que fazer?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Como já foi anteriormente falado nem sempre interessa o motivo de fechamento se é para a pergunta estar fechada mesmo.

Mas no caso desta pergunta: [Problemas em chamada PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31936/problemas-em-chamada-php) acho que o motivo de fechamento não tem nada a ver, o que pode levar a mas interpretações do AP.

O que fazer nestes casos?

Comment: O chato é que às vezes não mostra o voto separado por motivos. Relacionado: [*Could the close vote banner please be made less… well, wrong?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/185667)

Comment: É, fica parecendo que eu votei errado. Meu voto foi para não claro.

Comment: Outro detalhe importante é que o meu voto foi dado em um momento da pergunta e os outros votos em outro momento. Mais tarde não sei se daria o mesmo voto, talvez retiraria meu, mas depois que houve o fechamento fica lá o meu voto que talvez esteja fora do contexto. É um problema que não é fácil resolver mas pelo menos dizer quem votou em que já ajudaria. Parece que uma dificuldade com UI é mais importante do que dar uma informação mais correta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como o @bfavaretto disse, o problema nessa questão é que os 5 votos de fechamento não "combinaram". 4 deles votaram por `Fora de escopo -> outro` e o outro por `Não está claro`.

Quando isso acontece, o sistema decide pela maioria (no caso, "descontextualizado") e, como o `Fora de escopo -> outro` não possui uma mensagem padrão o sistema utilizou a mensagem default:

> Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na [help].

Apenas um dos votos de `off-topic` apresentava um motivo para o fechamento (problema muito específico), que ficou perdido entre os comentários da resposta. Dessa forma, a caixa de alerta realmente ficou descontextualizada (see what I did there?).

## Revisão dos fechamentos por escopo

Esse caso, e outros numa busca mequetrefe que fiz, mostram que precisamos organizar melhor nossos motivos de fechamento. Seja pela reescrita dos nossos motivos customizáveis ou por um [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso).

Particularmente, eu acredito que se forem criadas 15 novas razões para fechamento, todas elas vão ser usadas, muitas vezes sem necessidade. Então sou receoso quanto à isso. Mas acho que uma organizada básica, e uma estudada nos motivos do SOen, podem ajudar a manter as coisas em ordem.

### Escopo

Atualmente temos 3 razões de fechamento por escopo:

> **Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.**
>
> ---
>
> Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.
>
> ---
>
> This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese. It may be reopened if translated. ~ Esta pergunta não pertence ao site porque não está em Português. Poderá ser reaberta se for traduzida.

Sim, duas são iguais. A primeira, em negrito, é a default. Utilizada quando o motivo de fechamento não é unânime. Você pode ver [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3076/como-desbloquear-a-porta-80-do-firewall-do-windows-8) a diferença na caixa de alerta quando o motivo de fechamento é unânime.

Eu acho que poderíamos passar do modelo atual para:

> - Essa pergunta está fora do escopo do site, conforme definido na central de ajuda.
>
> ---
>
> 1. Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.
> 2. Esse problema **não pode ser reproduzido**, ou é um **erro de digitação**. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
> 3. Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque **não está em Português**. Poderá ser reaberta se for traduzida ~ This question is off-topic because it's **not written in Portuguese**. It may be reopened if translated.

É uma mistura do que temos hoje, com um motivo do SOen, e que evita a confusão que rolou nessa pergunta

## Update

Seguindo sugestão do Bacco, todos os Stack Overflows internacionais vão ter **4 motivos de fechamento por escopo**. Um deles já vai vir como "Essa pergunta está em Inglês", por padrão.

Comment: +1 gostei da ideia, Acho que são os 3 principais razões por escopo.

Comment: Alterei os motivos. Acho que a sugestão do @Bacco, de tirar "essa pergunta está em Inglês" dos motivos customizáveis é boa. Vou levar aos devs.

Comment: "Apenas um dos votos de off-topic apresentava um motivo para o fechamento" `-->` Acho que na verdade os outros 3 escolheram o motivo criado pelo primeiro que votou. O sistema oferece os motivos personalizados já criados para a pergunta. Cada voto nele vale um upvote no comentário automático com o texto do motivo.

Answer (score 2):

Não está exatamente errado. Foi usado um motivo personalizado de fechamento, e nesses casos o sistema mostra apenas o motivo mais genérico ("off-topic") no aviso, e mantém o [comentário que contém o motivo personalizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31936/problemas-em-chamada-php#comment60217_31936). Acredito que a intenção seja não colocar uma chancela oficial num motivo redigido pelos usuários (que pode até acabar sendo ofensivo, quem sabe).

---

Como temos um motivo personalizado dentro de *descontextualizado* que fala sobre a pergunta não ser sobre programação, o banner genérico poderia ser mais neutro. Em vez de incluir

> - Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.

ele poderia dizer:

> - Essa pergunta está fora do escopo do site, conforme definido na central de ajuda.

Comment: Eu sugeriria o adicionar o último motivo de off-topic como "específico demais" mas não sei se já é a hora

Comment: Mais ou menos como o que foi sugerido [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1590/sinaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-por-erro-tipogr%C3%A1fico-problema-que-n%C3%A3o-pode-ser-reproduzido)? Eu gosto de "específico demais", mas como lembra o extinto *too localized* talvez seus colegas de SE não gostem muito.

Comment: Minha preocupação vai menos de *como* escrever, e sim de se é necessário gastar nosso **último** OT-reason com isso

Comment: A propósito, tem como reivindicarmos mais motivos se necessário? O SOen tem mais de 3. Que injustiça! :) Falando sério, como só temos mais um, sou a favor de que seja o mais genérico possível.

Comment: Vou ver essa questão do número de OTs, mas certamente não precisamos de mais *agora*

Comment: bfavaretto e @Gabe: acho que um bom argumento pra ter ao menos mais um (quando chegar a hora) é que um dos _custom_ na verdade não deveria ser considerado _custom_, que é o de outra língua. Afinal, esse _off-topic_ deve ser uma extensão natural dos sites "não em inglês".

Comment: @bfavaretto sim mas o motivo é "Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda." o que dá a entender outra coisa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Atualizei a resposta com uma possível solução para isso.

Comment: @Gabe O que acha da sugestão que incluí acima?

Comment: Concordo com o bfavaretto. E com o @Gabe sobre o 'específico demais'.

Comment: @Bacco Faz sentido. Vou ver isso essa semana.

Comment: Quanto à sugestão do @bfavaretto, acho que ela é corretíssima. Mas, pelo que vi quanto ao sistema de tradução, precisaria ser pedida como um `feature-request`. Vou avaliar o caso e faço um post novo explicando a situação e vocês dão uma olhada.

Comment: Aborta tudo que eu disse no comentário anterior....